# Selecting duplicate site_id's

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    deal.*,
    site.name AS site_name
FROM deal
INNER JOIN site ON site.id = site_id
WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
GROUP BY deal.id DESC, site_id
LIMIT 5
```

This query works great, except that it's pulling duplicate site_ids....

I haven't been able to resolve this issue, this query doesn't work either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    site.name AS site_name,
    site.woot_off,
    woot_deal.*
FROM site
INNER JOIN woot_deal ON woot_deal.site_id = site.id
WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
GROUP BY woot_deal.id DESC, site_id
LIMIT 5
```

Each site has many deals, but I only want the latest of each of the deals.  This query is pulling 3 of 5 roles belonging to the same site.

Comment: Some info on your table structures would help?

Comment: I am assuming your relation between site and deals will be one to many. And in that case it is perfect that it's getting duplicate site_ids.

Comment: that means that there must be multiple deals per site, if this is the case, and you only want to return one deal, you need to provide some means of telling the DB _which_ deal you want to return, either with a where or having clause

Comment: Ah the good old woot-off... Do you have a special siren for a Bandolier of Carrots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
    deal.*,
    site.name AS site_name
from (
    SELECT max(deal.id) as deal_id, site_id
    FROM deal
    INNER JOIN site ON site.id = deal.site_id
    WHERE site.id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    GROUP BY site.id
) last_deals
inner join site on site.id = last_deals.site_id
inner join deal on deal.id = last_deals.deal_id
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer seems to be be far to complex by creating the anonymous table with a subquery.  Unless I am missing something a simple group by function should do the trick:

```
mysql> select * from site;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | lameone    |
|  2 | anotherone |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from deal;
+----+---------+-------+-------+
| id | site_id | name  | value |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | best  |    10 |
|  2 |       1 | worst |     1 |
|  3 |       2 | best  |    10 |
|  4 |       2 | worst |     1 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql>\p
--------------
select s.name site
     , d.name 
     , max(d.value) value
  from deal d
     , site s
 where s.id = d.site_id
 group by s.id
 order by 1,2,3

--------------

    -> \g
+------------+------+-------+
| site       | name | value |
+------------+------+-------+
| anotherone | best |    10 |
| lameone    | best |    10 |
+------------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```